# Seaborn/Matplotlib: How do I assign custom names to the lines that represent distributions on a KDE plot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm making a KDE plot of two different-sized 1D Numpy-arrays with Seaborn.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# dummy data:
array1 = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
array2 = np.random.randint(10, size=15)

sns.displot([array1, array2], kind="kde")
```

How do I assign custom names to the lines that represent the distributions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is useful for showing how to modify the legend text, but in this case I think a better approach is to give seaborn the names you want to use:

```
sns.displot({"zero": array1, "one": array2}, kind="kde")
```

[image]

This way requires less coding, and (more importantly) it doesn't run the risk of having the labels you set in the legend get out of sync with the order of data you pass to `displot`.

Comment: Wow, such syntax was my first instinct! Why didn't I try it, man? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the legend in this case, use `fig.lengend[0]` to get the legend text, and update it.

import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

```
# dummy data:
array1 = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
array2 = np.random.randint(10, size=15)

grid = sns.displot([array1, array2], kind="kde")
lg = grid.fig.legends[0] 
lg.texts[0].set_text('ZERO')
lg.texts[1].set_text('ONE')
```

[image]

Comment: While useful to know how to reach into the legend and modify the text, I think it's better to keep the names and the data associated from the beginning, if possible (and it is here).